# Android - Getting signal strength makes my App not responsive

Tags: performance, android, android-anr-dialog

I have an Android app that connects through GPRS. In one of my activities, I am checking the GSM signal strength with a PhoneStateListener. Depending on the strength I am updating an image (strong signal, weak signal...)

Here's the listener I am using:

```
     private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{
    /* Get the Signal strength from the provider, each tiome there is an update */
    @Override
    public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
    {
        super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);

        Log.v("final","signal strength: "+signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength());

        if (signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() < 5  ||  signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() == 99)
        {
            //poor connection or no connection

            signal.setImageResource(R.drawable.signal_poor);

        }
        else if(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() >= 5 && signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() < 8)
        {
            signal.setImageResource(R.drawable.signal_very_poor);
        }
        else if(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() >= 8 && signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() < 12)
        {
            signal.setImageResource(R.drawable.signal_medium);
        }

        else if(signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength() >= 12)
        {
            signal.setImageResource(R.drawable.signal);

        }



    }

};
```

and in onCreate() method I am initiating the listener:

```
          MyListener   = new MyPhoneStateListener();
    Tel = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
```

The problem is that sometimes when accessing the activity, I am getting ANR in (my package), Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut

```
      09-11 12:04:02.125    1270-1309/system_process E/ActivityManager﹕ ANR in com.example.myApp (com.example.myApp/.myActivity)
Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
Load: 1.84 / 1.26 / 0.53
CPU usage from 9732ms to 3045ms ago:
76% 1916/gsm0710muxd_bp: 12% user + 64% kernel / faults: 1 minor
10% 1875/com.example.universalapp: 8.1% user + 2.8% kernel / faults: 1488 minor 4 major
6.3% 1270/system_server: 5.4% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 481 minor 2 majo
```

these functions are consuming 76% of the CPU? they're that heavy? How can run them without affecting the UI and still update the UI whenever the signal strength changes?

Comment: You could lookup how it is done for the Android OS. How frequently is the listener triggered? Also how often does it change? It is possible that the data is very volatile and you want to take the running average of the past 5, 10, 100 signals. It also may be an issues of needing to cash your images.

Comment: @cyroxis, I dont control when it's called, but from observation every 2 seconds the level changes. Can it set to check very 5 seconds instead of when the value changes?
On another note, can you elaborate a bit about cashing the images? The images I am using are saved in Drawable, should I cache them in code?